# Running a C language program in PHP using proc_open

Tags: php, c, gcc

I am using `proc_open` to run the command : `gcc filename.c -o filename1`
to compile the C program.

And then the command : `./filename1` to execute the program.

Is it the right way to implement a simple C Compiler in PHP?

Please inform me about the possible security issues and how to fix them.

Comment: Running an arbitrary code received from client on the server is a one big security issue.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have taken a few security measures like, the active user account doesnt have root access on server. Also, if a program runs for more than 5 seconds, I am forcefully killing the process.

Comment: Then think what can a user without a root access do in 5 seconds on your server.

Comment: With that code, I would inject a `rm *` command

Comment: @Forbs Can you share a simple C program with `rm *` command in it.

Comment: @Forbs First I would try to find some passwords around..

Comment: This is a really bad idea, in fact most hosts will turn off compiler access because this is such a huge security issue.

Comment: Sorry iamabhishek, I'm not posting code that will directly help someone destroy machines.  I'm just showing you an example of how to someone can put something into your program to do that.

Comment: @Forbs I am trying to build a compiler for a website to help users practice coding using online Compiler. For Java I plan to use the policy file to allow user to perform only a set of commands. But in C there is no such way.

Does having a policy file using `java.security.manager` to execute Java program of any help in case of Java Compiler ?

Comment: Instead of building this yourself I'm sure there are other ways to train someone how to code other than giving them direct access to a program where 'children looking for fun' erase your system.  I once gave a Person access to PHPMYADMIN to add users. (Because they claimed to be safe and knew how to use it)  I go to lunch, and come back to find out she has pushed DROP TABLE just to see what it did. /sigh